# "Exists" keyword with false positive result - Robot Framework with Sikuli

Tags: python, automation, robotframework, sikuli

The "Exists" keywords is it assertive?

I added this keyword in my test (the objective is failed test, because i put a different image of the displayed screen), but the status is passed!

Which of these keywords is better to validate?

"**Exists**" or "**Screen Should Contain**"?

Is there a keyword where I validate the text presented on the screen with the text I send?

Comment: Could anyone help me?!

Comment: What library to use the project test?

Comment: I'm using the Sikuli Library in Robot Framework, Defandi...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm prefer to use keyword `Screen Should Contain` because different image